# Edit Ubuntu ISO

Tags: ubuntu, distributions

Maybe some of you know how to add apps to an Android ROM before it is installed (put them in /system/app). So I wanted to know if there is any way to configure an Ubuntu ISO this easy. I want to add some programs, add my user account, modify the desktop environment.

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools which do what you want. A good keyword to list them in your favorite search engine is `custom ubuntu ISO`.

Some suggestions:

- [Ubuntu Builder](http://lifehacker.com/5921054/ubuntu-builder-lets-you-build-your-own-customized-linux-distribution)
- [Official Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization)

Comment: Okay, i will google this.